# Как пробросить COM порт в другу машину?

Tags: ubuntu, com-port

Есть GSM модем который подключен к железной машине /dev/ttyS0 на OS Ubuntu, модем рабочий, смс с помощью gnokii отправляется.

Конфиг gnokii для отправки:

```
[global]
port = /dev/ttyS0
model = AT
initlength = default
connection = serial
use_locking = no
serial_baudrate = 115200
```

Как пробросить модем в другую машину под управлением OS Ubuntu используя Socat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SERVER в котором установлен модем в COM port:
socat -d -d -d  /dev/ttyS0,nonblock,raw,echo=0 TCP-LISTEN:1234,fork&

CLIENT: 
socat -d -d -d PTY,link=/dev/YPort TCP:192.168.1.1:1234&
```

UPDATE:

```
SERVER в котором установлен модем в COM port:
nohup socat -d -d -d  /dev/ttyS0,nonblock,raw,echo=0 TCP-LISTEN:1234,fork&

CLIENT: 
nohup socat -d -d -d PTY,link=/dev/YPort TCP:192.168.1.1:1234&
```